# Parallel downloading webpages by reading a list of URLs using wget through perl script

Tags: multithreading, perl, wget

I need to download huge number of ( say 1000) small pages with recursion level 1 using wget in parallel using perl by reading urls from a text file. The webpages are similar with just a single embedded object. I need set of 100 pages to be fetched in paralle so that the process is complete in 10 steps for example.
I am not sure whether to go ahead with threads in Perl or use some wget option to do so.
Can someone please help me with a code snippet to do this.

I have written following routine to do the following.

1. Create 100 threads and run them concurrently.
2. I pass count as parameter to subroutine
3. Send wget request for each webpage starting from page1.html to page100.html based on value of count.

Is this correct ?

```
use Threads;

print "Started at: ", time, "\n";
print "Starting main program\n";

my @threads;
for ( my $count = 1; $count <= 100;$count++) {
    my $t = threads->new(\&sub1,$count);
    push(@threads,$t);
}

foreach (@threads) {
    $_->join;
}

print "End of main program\n";
print "Stopped at: ", time, "\n";

sub sub1 {
    my $count = shift;
    print "Called at: ", time, "\n";
    sleep 2;
    #Send wget requests
    system(wget -r -l 1 http://path/page.$count.\.html);
}
```

Comment: Sure.  `man wget` should get you started.

Comment: man wget doesn't give any such options

Comment: Please make the question clearer, like, providing proper url example to test, the old code you are dealing with, do you need either `wget` or `perl`? , are you allowed to use perl to execute external command? and why parallel+wget doesn't serve your purpose? etc.

Comment: yes I can use wget through perl by logging to unix machine .. the key problem is i need to recursively download 1000 pages 100 at a time

Comment: and what the problem on using either `xargs` or `parallel`? they don't exist on the unix machine?

Comment: I tested, it works with -P 150. so, I think it should work for >100+ . Can you answer my question above?

Answer (score 6):

As you said "by reading urls from a text file".
You can do that by reading each line and print it out to STDOUT, but I don't think you really need Perl in this case.

You can use `wget` with options you want like -r, -l and turn off the verbose with -nv, then write to the urls.txt file. For instance, to download http://brew.sh site, you could do like:

```
wget -nv -r -l 1 http://brew.sh 2>&1 | grep "URL:" | awk '{print $3}'|sed 's/URL://' > urls.txt
```

You can simply use `cat` and GNU Findutils (xargs) with -P option or GNU Parallel with -j option to specify number of jobs you want. Like so:

```
cat urls.txt | xargs -n 1 -P 5 wget
```

Or

```
cat urls.txt | parallel -j 5 wget
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Also, example: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example__breadth_first_parallel_web_crawler_mirrorer

Comment: I need to recursively download webpage till first level and hence wget .

Comment: Edited the answer, you can just use `wget -nv -r -l 1` to write urls to a file. then use those commands in example above. either `xargs' or `parallel'.

Comment: @zdk Change the answer to include 'wget -nv -r -l 1'. Also I am trying to figure out how `perl -ane 'print $_'` differs from `cat` If it does not, remove the 2 lines: They only confuse.

Comment: I don't think this serves the purpose. Perl is a must for me. I want some solution with perl.

Comment: @Dcoder And what the problem with https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager#Parallel-get ? there are many examples in the document. If you need a code example for your specific case. Please revise your question and make it clearer following your specific case like url example, the old code you are dealing with, why do you mix wget command and perl and why parallel+wget doesn't serve your perpose etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager) instead of threads and [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) instead of curl/wget.

A quick search of CPAN also turns up [LWP::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Parallel)

Comment: Can you please illustrate using an example.